# Удалить / добавить значение из флагов

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

Какими из операторов можно проверить присутствие флага, и удалить его если он есть, в противном случае добавить?

Значения флагов имеет тип `uint32_t`.

```
bool window::set_fullscreen(const bool value) const
{
    uint32_t flags = SDL_GetWindowFlags(m_window_.get());

    if(flags & SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    {
        if(value)
        {
            return true;
        }

        flags &= SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN; // удалить флаг если значение value false
    }
    else
    {
        // Тут необходимо добавить флаг в значение flags и вызвать соответствующую ф-цию
    }

    return SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(m_window_.get(), flags) == 0;
}
```

Comment: А что есть флаги в данном контексте?

Comment: Смотря что вы понимаете под флагом, и как именно вы планируете реализовать. В конце концов, строка `"yes"` - тоже может считаться флагом. Ваш вопрос в той форме, в какой он задан - некорректен...

Comment: переменную назвать флагом, еще не значит, что она яыляется флагом

Comment: @ARHovsepyan: А что насчет названия функции которая возвращает значение?

Comment: (для битовых флогов) Все это можно сделать побитовыми операциями. Причем первый пункт и так уже делается в примере. Непонятно, в чем вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если переменная флагов - `flags`, а конкретный бит - `mask` (например, 000100 в бинарной записи), то

Проверка установленности:

```
if (flags&mask) { установлен }
```

Установка флага:

```
flags |= mask;
```

Сброс флага:

```
flags &= ~mask;
```

Изменение флага на противоположный:

```
flags ^= mask;
```

Comment: добавить флаг :   flags = old_flags | mask;???

Comment: @MBo,  я поставил плюс, а потом задал вопрос: стоит ли добавить это?  Так что я не говорил, что что то не так

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Так ведь установить флаг - это как раз оно и есть..

Comment: Да, я  запарился со своими кодами и странными вопросами в  SO, извеняюсь

Comment: Если маска больше одного бита, то `xor` не поменяет флаг на противоположный, так как понятие противоположности в таких случаях остуствует.

Comment: @0andriy Забавный вы человек... Цитирую: "*а конкретный* **бит** *- mask (например, 000100 в бинарной записи)*" Ну кто мешает написать собственный *правильный* ответ?... Кстати, куда более умным было бы говорить тогда уж о проверке установленности - что это проверка установленности хотя бы одного бита, а проверка установленности всех - `if ((flags&mask) == mask)`

Comment: В вопросе ничего не было про единственность бита в маске, о чём я вам и говорю.

Comment: @0andriy Если бы вас интересовало сделать замечание *по существу*, а не просто так покрасоваться - то я вам показал, где его надо было делать: на проверке установленности нескольких битов. Там оно к месту. Но этого вы почему-то не увидели :)

Comment: Конечно, но там это очевидно, а вот с исключающим ИЛИ говорить о противоположности флага не имеет смысла для многобитовых последовательностей. Я уж не знаю, как ещё вам это объяснить.

Comment: И да, никто не сравнивает со «всех» в реальной жизни, если уж на то пошло, а делают *if ((flag & mask) == FLAG_IN_Q)*.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, флаги здесь соответствуют выставленным битам, например `FlagX = 0x00000800` означает, что 11-й бит установлен.

Для установки флага используется битовое ИЛИ

```
flags = flags | FlagX
```

Для сброса нужно, не портя других битов, обнулить конкретный. Для этого инвертируем константу флага (все биты становятся единичными, кроме данного) и выполняем битовое И

```
flags = flags & (~FlagX)
```